# How to tell if a website is static or dynamic?

Tags: javascript

My prof said that dynamic pages get created by the computer, while static pages are created by the user.

Thank you so much!

Comment: yeah you're right. without going on it I can say that it's dynamic because of the fact that it displays content that changes. your CSS tag doesn't make much sense seeing as the webpage should look effectively the same, regardless of the content value.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding: "How to tell if a website is static or dynamic?"
Static websites are simple web pages (typically written in languages like **JavaScript**, **HTML**, **CSS**, etc.) and *stored in a web server*. In the case of static web pages, as soon as a server receives a request for a page, it immediately sends a response to the client with no additional processing. Users will always view the same content regardless of their location, device type, and web browser.

In static websites, the displayed content remains the same unless someone **manually** edits the *HTML source code* on every page that’s part of the website. These pages contain no alterations based on any user input. Hence the name- static web pages. You don't necessarily need any prior experience with database design and web programming to create and maintain a static website. As long as they don't change when we update them, the code for static web pages stays the same.

On the other hand, Dynamic web pages have greater complexity than static ones because they display different content for each user while retaining the same layout and design. A dynamic website generates web pages in *real-time*. The flexible nature of the content allows for customization based on the requests from the user or the browser used by them. Such pages are usually written in languages like **CGI**, **AJAX**, **ASP** or **ASP.NET**, and they usually take more time to load than static web pages. They are frequently implemented to show information that changes frequently, e.g., *weather updates, stock prices, etc.*

Server-side code used to construct a dynamic web page can generate *real-time HTML pages* for each request from an individual user. While static websites are mostly informational, dynamic websites contain interactive, continually changing elements. In order to provide an interactive website experience for visitors, web developers usually combine both client-side and server-side programming techniques.

Dynamic web pages usually contain application programs for various services and require server-side resources like databases. A dynamic website accesses content from a **CMS** (Content Management System), which means that the website reflects any changes made in the database content. These sites use *client-side scripting*, *server-side scripting*, or *both* for generating content. Separating the site’s design from its content makes it easier for web designers to create pages without having to worry about formatting issues. After uploading content into the database, websites retrieve their content from there when responding to user requests.

Now, regarding "Would [www.tagpro.gg](http://www.tagpro.gg) (the homepage) be static or dynamic?"
I have visited the homepage and it is a dynamic webpage actually as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

> My prof said that dynamic pages get created by the computer, while static pages are created by the user.

Well, actually also static pages can be generated by the computer, since there are a lot of static sites generators out there. Take for example https://astro.build or https://gohugo.io

> Would [www.tagpro.gg](http://www.tagpro.gg)  be static or dynamic?

You are right, it is dynamic, since you can see a login/sign-up feature on the page. That's nothing you can achieve with a 100% static site.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between static pages and dynamic pages.

1. a static page has a generic URL suffix, such as .htm, .html, .shtml, and does not contain "?";
2. Websites using dynamic page skills can perform more functions such as user registration, login, online survey, user management, order management, etc.;

Application and web languages:

- Static web pages: `HTML, JavaScript, CSS`, etc.
- Dynamic Web Pages: `PHP, CGI, AJAX, ASP, ASP.NET`, etc.

> Dynamic web pages are used where information changes frequently, such as stock prices, weather information, news and sports news.

- Static web pages have fixed content, while dynamic web pages can have changing content.
- Static web pages must be modified manually, while changes to a dynamic page can be loaded through an application whose resources are stored in a database.
- Static web pages only use a web server, while dynamic web pages use a web server, an application server, and a database.

Answer (score -2):

Its very simple... Only major two factors matter -

1. A static website does not have artificial intelligence means it cannot add something automatically the user has to type the code for that is he wants to do so but a dynamic website can do it on its own.
2. A static website cannot store a information means it only includes frontend no backend no php, node.js or something like that. In simpler words if user signin to your website  you would not able to store his username and password.